# Executing Powershell script via CMD

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, scripting

I have this powershell script which is called change.ps1, here is the content of the script:

```
Param([string]$username, [string]$password)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$newpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$password" -AsPlainText –Force
Set-ADAccountPassword $username -NewPassword $newpwd –Reset
```

I now try to run this script via cmd.exe, here is the command i use (note that i pass two parameters which are used in the script above):

```
powershell.exe C:\inetpub\htdocs\school_panel\scripts\change.ps1 -username "test" -password "Elgoog321"
```

Now, when i run this command i can tell the script is found and executed as the second line works. I know this because i can see the module being imported. However, after i get this error message: 
http://puu.sh/aXuH3/b8db154625.png

I would be very grateful if someone could offer some help on this.

Regards

Comment: your image seems to indicate an encoding pb. Did you copy/paste your command ? try to retype it manualy please

Comment: Retype it? why? i dont get where you are getting at.

Comment: this is working here... from where do you launch the command ? cmd.exe ?

Comment: @Kayasax yes, i launch from cmd.exe

Comment: what happens if you launch a powershell console then call your script ?

Comment: @Kayasax I get the same error.

Comment: open your script with notepad++ and try to convert to ansi encoding?

Comment: I'm writing it as an answer if  you want to accept it so your question wont be flag as unanswered ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your image seems to indicate an encoding pb. Maybe you have paste the command from another file with a wrong encoding.
Try to open your file in notepad++ and  convert it to ANSI encoding

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a powershell via CMD you need to grand execution permissions to that powershell file. You need to add the parameters **-executionpolicy** with the attribute **remotesigned**. Here an example on a batch file:

```
@echo off
echo Executing powershell...
cd "C:\directory\of\my\powershell"
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "drive:\Directory\of\my\powershell\mypowershell.ps1"
```

then you can execute your powershell with no problems inside the CMD window, even if you are not administrator.

Comment: Im checking it, seems your web user does not have enough rights to execute it. try to execute your bat file through a CMD to see the desired result. Please contact me through wizpert so we can do a remote session, probably we need to configure IIS to make sure the script can be executed properly (rights permissions). If I'm not available, leave me a message and we can make time for you yo work with.